# Create distinct non-overlapping polygons from overlapping polygons in Geopandas/Python

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

Given a GeoDataFrame with some overlapping polygons (buffers), I would like to create unique, non overlapping polygons where there are overlaps and also retain the non-overlapping polygons. The output would have no overlapping polygons. This functionality is available in ArcMap/ArcGIS Desktop using the feature-to-polygon tool:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-polygon.htm

I have tried many different things, but cannot seem to get it quite right. Thanks for any help.

Edit to add example:

```py
#example
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)])
polys['geometry'] = polys.buffer(1)

ax2 = polys.plot(figsize=(5,5), edgecolor=u'white', color='gray')

colors = [1,2,3,4]
for name in (colors):
    polys.loc[polys['id'].eq(name)].plot(edgecolor=u'white', color=np.random.rand(3,), ax=ax2)

ax2.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Sorry, hopefully what I just added helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`polygonize`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.polygonize.html) the [`unary_union`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union.html) of the [`exterior`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.exterior.html) of each separate polygon :

```
from shapely.ops import polygonize    

nonov_polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list(
        polygonize(polys.exterior.unary_union)))

print(nonov_polys.shape[0]) # 9 polygons

nonov_polys.plot(ec="w", cmap="plasma"); # + plt.text for annotations
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have tried many different things using overlays, including looping through each poly, running intersect & difference on the rest of the features., adding them to a new GeoDataFrame...but cant get it quite right. I tried your suggestion, but it does not appear to work when there are multiple overlaps.

Comment: Your question still lack of specifics but I updated my answer to give you the general logic.

Comment: Thanks. Still having trouble getting this to produce exactly what I am looking for. The desired output in this example is a geodataframe containing 9 non-overlapping polygons. So it would have 9 rows, one for each non-overlapping polygon. Here is a shapefile representation: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wokkNbxuL6FANg8ooU8OWxjOLkKnuXPL?usp=drive_link

Comment: Got you, the updated answer should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that works and a one-liner to boot! Thanks so much- really appreciate it!